git log --since will miss some commits
I have a branch that merged some merge requests from other repositories, which resulted in non-linear committed time on my branch. When I use git log --since and traverse from HEAD to the parent commit until the first commit that does not meet the condition, it stops. Is there a way for me to continue retrieving the commits that may satisfy the condition afterwards.
Assume that a branch with commits " A->B->C->D ",the committed time are 2:00, 3:00, 2:15, 2:16.
I got a result "A" when i use git log --since, how can i get A,C,D?

As it's not clear what the log graph is, I'd suggest you try --since-as-filter instead of --since. --since-as-filter was introduced in a relatively new version. If your Git does not support it yet, try a new version.

While this may appear to be a duplicate of this older question, (at least in terms of the answers it garners), I think its clarity is significantly better than that question. If either question is marked duplicate, it should be the older one.
